# WSO2 analytics datasource

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I was trying to explore the analytics event & summary datasource.
I have installed a  H2 client and found strange tables names (**ANX___7LKA5XV8_**!!)

Why using these names, I was expecting a more clear names (names like the ones used in the external DB,the one partaged with the API manager)?
And is there any documentation about these tables?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please list the products with the versions you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These tables represent the data that you've set to be persisted on the WSO2 Analytics product. For each stream definition that you have, there will be a corresponding table in the analytics datasource.

The reason the names look strange is because the table names are encoded. The records within these tables are encoded as well. The data is encoded in such a way so that various data types could be seamlessly handled in a DB-agnostic manner.

WSO2 recommends that you either use the [Data Explorer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Data+Explorer) menu item or the [Analytics REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/REST+APIs+for+Analytics+Data+Service) to view the contents of the analytics datasources, rather than browse them at a DB-level.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Gokul,
This seems very helpful.
I have another question please: I'm trying to deploy new data publisher car.
I looked at tthe APIM_LAST_ACCESS_TIME_SCRIPT.xml spark script (used by api manager) and didn't understand the difference between the two temporaries tables created: **API_LAST_ACCESS_TIME_SUMMARY_FINAL** and **APILastAccessSummaryData**

Comment: Would you mind asking this as a separate question, since others who have a similar problem might also find it more easily. Also, if the above is the answer you're looking for, please mark it as answered. Thanks.